# Как передать объект File (javascript) через channels для сохранения в поле django ImageField

Tags: javascript, django, django-channels

Преобразовывая File в Blob, проверяю в консоли, что в Blob успешно преобразовался и в массив добавился, но при получение каналом получаю пустой массив с пустыми словарями.

```
var images_input = document.getElementById('images_input');
let images = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < images_input.files.length; i++) {
   var file_type = images_input.files[i].type;
   const blob = new Blob([images_input.files[i]], { type: file_type })
   images.push(blob);
};
chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
   /// другие данные
  'images': images
}));
```

Модель в django:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    # другие данные
    image = models.ImageField()
```

Я пробовал отправлять просто FileList, но данные тоже не приходили.

В какой тип данных и как преобразовать File,чтобы он и передался успешно и сохранить удалось?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ты про ArrayBuffer забыл. Большинство того что тебе может пригодится ты найдёшь вот в этом примере.

```html
<body>
  <input type="file" id="filename" />
  <input type="button" value="Connect" onclick="connectChatServer()" />
  <input type="button" value="Upload" onclick="sendFile()" />
  <script>
var ws;
function connectChatServer() {
  ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1");
  ws.binaryType = "arraybuffer";
  ws.onopen = function() {
    alert("Connected.")
  };
  ws.onmessage = function(evt) {
    alert(evt.msg);
  };
  ws.onclose = function() {
    alert("Connection is closed...");
  };
  ws.onerror = function(e) {
    alert(e.msg);
  }
}

function sendFile() {
  var file = document.getElementById('filename').files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  var rawData = new ArrayBuffer();            
  reader.loadend = function() {
  }
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    rawData = e.target.result;
    ws.send(rawData);
    alert("the File has been transferred.")
  }
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Мешал ещё `JSON.stringify`, без него ArrayBuffer стал приходить